# How to define new attribute in python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I wrote a class like which has 3 hidden attributres:

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, name, model, brand):
        self.__name = name
        self.__model = model
        self.__brand = brand
```

Is that possible to create a method for this class to set a new attribute (publisher)?
I wrote this one, but I didn't get result:

```
    def set_publisher(self, publisher):
        self.__publisher = publisher


b1 = Car(name="X", model="Y", brand="Z")
publisher="D"
b1.set_publisher(publisher)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'set_publisher'
```

Comment: It has no attribute `set_publisher`.
But once you've called `set_publisher()` it should have a `__publisher` attribute.

Comment: Is that possible to not define the publisher in __init__() ?

Comment: I reproduced your issue.
Try using variables prefixed by a single underscore (not 2).
It works for me when replacing `__publisher` by `_publisher`.
I believe double underscore prefixed variables are reserved.
Unless you really want `__` variables.

Comment: @danial Please provide reproducible example. Your code works just fine when pasting it directly into the IDE, no changes done.

Comment: Strange.
Can you double-check indentation ?
Does the `set_publisher()` function belong to the class ?
A simple indentation error could lead to that issue. I've tried it.

Comment: It's not considered good style to write setters like this. Just make `publisher` public, and if you change your mind later, you can replace it with a property.

Comment: @0x0fba `__publisher` is not reserved (`__publisher__` is, with trailing underscores as well). But people often use names subject to name mangling when a single underscore to mark it as "not part of the public interface" would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem if `set_publisher` is correctly defined as an instance method.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name, model, brand):
        self.__name = name
        self.__model = model
        self.__brand = brand

    def set_publisher(self, publisher):
        self.__publisher = publisher
```

But if the setter does nothing but allow any value to be assigned directly to the attribute, why bother hiding it? Just make `publisher` a public attribute:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name, model, brand, publisher=None):
        self.__name = name
        self.__model = model
        self.__brand = brand
        self.publisher = None  # Define but None is usually better than undefined

c = Car("Dave", "Model T", "Ford")
c.publisher = "Henry"
```

If you later decide to impose further restrictions on how (or if) the publisher can be set, you can replace it with a property without changing the interface of your class.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name, model, brand, publisher=None):
        self.__name = name
        self.__model = model
        self.__brand = brand
        self._publisher = None

    @property
    def publisher(self):
        return self._publisher

    @publisher.setter
    def publisher(self, value):
        # If you want to examine value and reject it,
        # do so and raise a ValueError. You can modify
        # value before assigning it as well.

        if value == "Bob":
            raise ValueError("Bob is not a publisher")
        if value == "Alice":
            # Alice changed her name a while ago
            value = "Carol"
        self._publisher = value

c = Car("Dave", "Model T", "Ford")
c.publisher = "Henry"  # OK
c.publisher = "Alice"  # assert c.publisher == "Carol"
c.publisher = "Bob"  # ValueError
```

Comment: Nitpick: `set_publisher` would be a method (or "instance method" or "method on the class"), not a class method (which is a different thing entirely, produced with `@classmethod`).

Comment: I could argue a distinction between "class method" and `classmethod`, but honestly, I think my fingers were just on autopilot :) I'll fix.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code to use a method (wrapper of `setattr`) to add attributes by name and value:

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name, model, brand):
        self.__name = name
        self.__model = model
        self.__brand = brand

    def set_attribute(self, attr_name, value):
        setattr(self, attr_name, value)


obj = Car(name="name", model="model", brand="brand")
obj.set_attribute("__publisher", "publisher")
print(obj.__publisher)
```

```bash
>>> publisher
```

Comment: This bypasses the name-mangling private attributes are supposed to have, which actually makes it impossible to access it normally (without `getattr`/`setattr`) from within any methods on the class.